# WHQL -DP WLK - Hot-Replace - Device Test - Verify driver support for D3 power state

Tags: windows

I am trying to Run WLK Tests for Windows server 2008R2 , so as to get certified from microsoft. My driver is a filter driver.

The problem is that the following tests wont start at all.

[DP WLK - Hot-Add - Device Test - Verify driver support for Hot-Add CPU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj125231.aspx)

[DP WLK - Hot-Replace - Device Test - Verify driver support for D3 power state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh998208.aspx)

I am unable to deduce the Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Use `Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacentre` Not Just `windows Server 2008 R2` . Check in Job `constraints` of that particular job in `DTM Studio`.

Answer (score 0):

What hardware are you running the test on?  I am running into the same issue and I am thinking it has to do with the client hardware I am using is not server hardware.  It is multicore but single CPU.

Comment: Based on the reply from rakesh, I checked the contraints and it does require datacenter.  Why? And why would there not be a separate cert for Datacenter then.